# MySQL Selecting Something with Array Information

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x CONTAINS "1"
```

Basically, I want to select data from the database where x contains a specific number. The thing is, the x column in any row could contain "1, 2, 3" and I want to select all those that contain 1, specifically 1, not 11 or anything that contains 1, but specifically a 1.

Here's an example:

```
id   title   x
-------------------
1    row1    1,22,3
2    row2    1,5
3    row3    5,91
4    row4    70
```

And I want my query to return rows 1 and 2. I don't want row 3, as the 1 is inside the number 91. I don't want row 4 because there's no 1 there either.

Comment: Why is x column a list of integers as a string?

Comment: Separate x values to a different table, then use joins. This way you're just shooting yourself in the leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FIND_IN_SET function like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', x)
```

This will also get optimised to use bit arithmetic if you are calling it on a SET type.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd normalize your 'x' column out to a separate table.

But... you could also hack it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x LIKE '%,1' OR x LIKE '1,%' OR x LIKE '%,1,%'
```

This basically just handles the three different cases where the "1" is the first, last or a middle element in your list. (note if you've got a space after your commas you'd change the last part to '%, 1,%'

EDIT: Actually Dmitriy's REGEXP is nicer, and a'r's FIND_IN_SET looks ideal.

Comment: It's easier to do this: `CONCAT(',', x, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x REGEXP "(^|,)1(,|$)"
```